# Generate multiple arrays simultaniously in python

Tags: python, arrays, function

Assuming that `amount` is the amount of the array, and `b` is the length of an array. I have no idea how to fill this

```
def MultiList(amount,length)
```

I want to if i call `MultiList` function like

```
MultiList(5,5)
```

Yhe output will be

```
(array ([0,0,0,0,0]), array ([0,0,0,0,0]), array ([0,0,0,0,0]), array ([0,0,0,0,0]),array ([0,0,0,0,0]))
```

Comment: You're just after a list of lists?

Comment: `tuple(np.zeros(length) for _ in range(amount))`?

Comment: If you are using NumPy, go with the answer of Md. Rezwanul Haque (or the comment from @Goyo). If you mean built in lists, go with the answer of RomanPerekhrest or mine.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo thanks, let see there's any possible solution outthere?

Comment: You've got 4 answers already. All of them give a list/array containing `amount` number of lists/arrays filled with `length` number of zeros. They all answer your question. You only need to say if you are using built in list or NumPy array, since there's no `array` built in type in Python (there's `list` type) and you didn't mention `NumPy` where type `array` exists, so we are a little bit confused.

Answer (score 3):

For your simple case:

```
def gen_multi_list(amount, length, value=0):
    return [[value]*length for _ in range(amount)]

print(gen_multi_list(5,5))
```

The output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: You can add the lambda version: `gen_multi_list = lambda amount, length, value=0: [[value]*length for _ in range(amount)]` for a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy tuple` to do this task.

```
import numpy as np
def multilist(amount, length):
    return tuple(np.zeros(length, dtype=np.int) for _ in range(amount))
print(multilist(5,5))
```

Output :

```
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the multiple array just using consecutive loops in function. to create list of list then convert it into tuple as we want tuple like output.

```
def Multilist(amount, length):
    tup = [];
    for i in range(amount):
        arr = []
        for j in range(length):
            arr.append(0)
        tup.append(arr)
    return tuple(tup)
print(Multilist(5,5))
```

**Output :**

```
([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Multilist = lambda amount, length : tuple([[0]*amount ]*length)
print(Multilist(5,5))
```

Output:
`([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0])`

Comment: I like the lambda approach but using `[]*times` has a problem. Try the following: `m = Multilist(3,3)` `print(m)` `m[0][1] = 1` `print(m)`. The second print will be `([0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0])`

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo lambda removed in Python 3? Can you provide a link? Python 3.5 supports lambda functions.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I know the reason, your solution has the sime side-effect. I was just showing it to the users that may not know it.

Comment: Ok @Adirio I need a coffee before I write anything else here. Especially about lambdas... I know that my code has the same problem. It's the same family of issues as `def foo(bar=[])` causes. `def foo(bar=None)` is better. Thanks.

Comment: it means we cannot use anonymous function here right?

Comment: Not really, its not a problem of anonymous functions but of list multiplication. The outter list, the one you are converting to a touple, does not copy each of their elements, instead it stores the same reference. So basically you have a single list showing `amount` times. You would have to go for a list comprehension for that outter one as in RomanPerekhrest's answer. I actually comented on that answer how the lambda version of his method would be.

Comment: yeah, but that mean it couldn't be done in one  line hence we cannot use it

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo that's right, the default mutable arguments have the same kind of issue. Enjoy your coffee ;)

Comment: `Multilist = lambda amount, length, value=0: tuple([[value]*length for _ in range(amount)])` is a one-liner that even can provide a different default argument